# Crawling the timestamps of all the activities (clicks) on a video of another user with API v3 client library

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I want to get the time-stamped click-streams of views of a particular Youtube video of another user, so not of the logged in user. What parameter on Youtube API I need to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some statistics. If you hit this endpoint:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Then you will be returned the total viewcount, like count, dislike count, favorite count, and comment count. However, if you want more granular details (for example you mention time stamps), you'll need to have the video's owner authenticate to your site, and then use the Analytics API.

In other words, you can't do detailed data mining if you don't own the videos.

Comment: But i need that data to be able to do research. Is there anyway to get that data via crawling? I have done this before in Twitter. Twitter search and live stream returns all tweets related to the key-words that I had set.

Comment: Your comparison confused me a bit; Twitter search that returns all tweets related to a keyword would be like doing a YouTube search that returns all videos related to a keyword, which is certainly possible through the API. Your question seems to indicate you want the timestamps when particular videos were watched, is that correct? Or do you want to just know when they were published? The former is just not exposed through the API, nor through crawling; the latter, however, is doable. IF you could explain exactly the data you want, it may still be possible.